# Can't access the Amazon S3 data created by the master account in the member account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have created a Bucket using my organizational master account, and assigned it a bucket policy.

```
 {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1519198081967",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1519198076838",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::XXXX:root",
                    "arn:aws:iam::XXXX:root",
                    "arn:aws:iam::XXXX:root"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1519198076838",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::XXXX:root",
                    "arn:aws:iam::XXXX:root",
                    "arn:aws:iam::XXXX:root"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I try to access the bucket from the organizational member account that I have allowed to access the bucket I get error "Access Denied".

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>XXXXX</RequestId>
<HostId>
XXXXX
</HostId>
</Error>
```

What do I need to change in the Bucket policy to access my files from the member accounts.

Another pointer:

The file in my member account shows as :

> Server side encryption
>
> Access denied

Although, I have not configured any server side encryption in my bucket.

[UPDATE]

The file I am trying to access looks like this in the master account:

[image: Master account file]

And, the file in the member looks like this:

[image: member account file]

What I am pointing out is the absence of owner in the member account, could that be a cause of the issue.

Comment: How is the "member" accessing the file? Are they using the CLI/SDK? This way, their credentials are being passed to S3.

Comment: For now, I am just trying to download the files using the AWS console, later I will try to download it using boto3.

Comment: Note that *Server side encryption Access denied* simply means you lack the privilege to *ask* about encryption of the object.  It's the only property shown here that isn't provided by the List Objects APIs.  I suspect that the fact that your master account does not own the object is relevant, here.  Objects created by the master account in this bucket will probably work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You are granting access to an *Account*, which does not mean all its users also gain access.

Try a principal like:

```
arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT:user/*
```

Comment: I am not trying to access the file as a user, but as an organisational member root account itself, in fact I don't have any users presently.

Comment: Could this issue be because of the absence of the owner of the file in the member account, if so how could we resolve it?

Comment: You are using the Root user of an Account to access resources? This is discouraged because Root users have total access that cannot be restricted. You should always use IAM Users.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to share the KMS keys as well, as the bucket at your master account is encrypted.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/share-custom-encryption-keys-more-securely-between-accounts-by-using-aws-key-management-service/

Comment: the bucket in the master is not encrypted at all.

Comment: could the issue be because of the absence of owner for the file in the member account, I have attached screenshots to the original question above.

Comment: Can you check your permission for the bucket?
 step 2.3 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-walkthroughs-managing-access-example2.html#access-policies-walkthrough-cross-account-permissions-acctB-tasks